# Console Application Error on Windows 2012 server R2 standard application

Tags: windows, error-handling, console

I have created a console application in visual studio 2013 on windows server 2012 standard version and the exe file seems to run ok but when I copy it to the windows server 2012 R2 standard version it come up with the following error when I try to run it - Application erro - The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click ok to close the aplication. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: This is unlikely to be related to the version of Windows, by the way.  It probably works on the first machine only because Visual Studio 2013 is installed.  Try installing the Visual Studio runtime on the second machine and see if that helps, or change your build configuration to use the statically linked runtime.

Comment: I have looked in dependency walker and it show that some dll's are 64 bit but how do I replace these with the correct dll's and also how do I know which ones are which? I have a screen shot but not sure how I add it to this page

Answer (score 0):

It's look like your 32-bit application tried to load some 64-bit "dll".
Try to check by [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: I have looked in dependency walker and it show that some dll's are 64 bit but how do I replace these with the correct dll's and also how do I know which ones are which? I have a screen shot but not sure how I add it to this page.